# Как улучшить показатели WebVitals при использовании аналитики, особенно gtm?

Tags: html, google-analytics, gtm

Прежде чем кидаться в меня idle функциями, я уже пытался:

1. Сократить селекторы
2. Убрать всё lazyload(это улучшило,но не критично)
3. Сократить запросы xhr
4. Я убирал запросы в requestidlecallback
5. Так же убирал все dataLayer.push() в requestidlecallback, пробовал и в обычный setTimout()

Особенную проблему составляет google tab manager. Он есть у на и конкурента.
У конкрутента находится в basedoc, у нас же загружается скрипт в постзагрузке (onload), который подключает его. И наши метрики tti, tbt в 3 раза больше чем у конкурента. Если же перенести его в basedoc, то ничего не меняется, и см пункт 5, у конкурента и это не сделано, а метрики лучше.

Comment: Может попробуйте `link rel preload`?

Comment: на что именно? Для LCP стоит самая первая большая картинка в preload.
LH советует убрать шрифты, но я во-первых, поставил swap, во-вторых, гружу их так же в посзагрзке, то есть создаю ссылку на файл со шрифтами. 
Может preconnect имелось ввиду? Заметил сейчас у конкурентов на аналитику именно так идёт

Comment: Попробовал preconnect и вынести в basedoc. стало хуже.